# How to use GADRewardBasedVideoAd

Tags: ios, admob, chartboost, adcolony, applovin

I want to add reward ads in my application, when user watch the ads video i will give him a reward

what i try to do is something like this
in viewdidload i initialize like this :

```
 let rewardedVideo : GADRewardBasedVideoAd =    
  GADRewardBasedVideoAd.sharedInstance()
    rewardedVideo.delegate = self
    let request2 : GADRequest = GADRequest()
    request.testDevices = [kGADSimulatorID, "id_device"]
    rewardedVideo.load(request2, withAdUnitID: "id reward video from admob")
```

and later in the application when user decide to play video ads i check  this :

```
 if GADRewardBasedVideoAd.sharedInstance().isReady {

  GADRewardBasedVideoAd.sharedInstance().present(fromRootViewController: self)
        }
```

the problem is GADRewardBasedVideoAd.sharedInstance().isReady is alway no ready

how can i resolve this problem please ?

any help will be appreciated

___________________Edit

I added this

```
   func rewardBasedVideoAd(_ rewardBasedVideoAd:  GADRewardBasedVideoAd, didFailToLoadWithError error: Error?) {
    print("error \(error)")
}
```

and i can see error : Request Error: No ad to show

i don't know may be i miss a configuration

--------------Edit

Solution i used:

like @Daniel Storm  suggested, i have to configure third party ad networks for GADRewardBasedVideoAd but when i tried to connect AdColony and Applovin to admob its give me error, somehow adapter it s not connected correcety, i finally  choise to integrate chartboost independally of admob, so now i have chartboost for resward video and and admob for banner and intertitiel

i add chartboost like this :

```
       Chartboost.start(withAppId: "appid configurad in https://dashboard.chartboost.com", appSignature: "signature in the same site", delegate: self)
       Chartboost.cacheRewardedVideo(CBLocationMainMenu)


      if(Chartboost.hasRewardedVideo(CBLocationMainMenu)){


            Chartboost.showRewardedVideo(CBLocationMainMenu)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to setup and use third party ad networks for `GADRewardBasedVideoAd` on AdMob.com.

From [Rewarded Video: Publishers Get Started](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/ios/rewarded-video):

> Rewarded ads are only available from third-party networks that you've
>   selected for mediation.

Comment: FYI admob now support rewarded video that's to say you no need to setup third part networks.